# The pass password-manager do not link bash compleation to my ~/.password-store folder on Arch Linux

Tags: operating-systems, password-management

Have had this problem on two different Arch Linux machines in the past, but it have magically resolved itself after a day or two. The primary problem is that when I write `pass` and use Tab, bash do not place me in the `~/.password-store` folder to complete and go from there, but instead continues at the `./` folder as normal.
It have now gone a week and are tired of going into `~/.password-store/this/folder/and/this/file.gpg` and decrypt it by hand. Is this the cause of `pass` or `bash/zsh` (zsh is the one I use) to not find this directory? Cannot find anything about this in the [documentation](https://www.passwordstore.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800952/oh-my-zsh-plugins-not-working) thread. How I solved my problem was to re-run `source $HOME/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` even though it should have allready been executed in the ~/.zshrc file. Now bash completion in pass is working as expected under zsh.